# understanding intuitionistic logic

Tags: logic, intuitionistic-logic

Just started a chapter on Intuitionism, and already I'm kinda confused on how to structure a proof in favor of intuitionistic logic. Here are the following definitions I am supposed to use:

Intuitionistic logic definitions:

[image]

And so I made an attempt at the two following practice exercises from my textbook. They are classically valid but I am two show that they are also intuitionistically valid.

Exercise 1. ¬X v ¬Y => ¬(X & Y)

Attempt for 1: If we have a proof of the premise, then we have either a proof of ¬X or a proof of ¬Y. Assume now that we are given a proof of X. It follows that our first proof could not have been a proof of ¬X: for that would be a proof that X cannot be proved, and we are assuming that we have just been given a proof of X. So our first proof must in fact been a proof of ¬X and the other a proof of ¬Y.

Exercise 2:

[image]

Attempt for 2: Assume we are given a proof of its premise, then we have a proof that for some n, ¬Fn and for every n, we have either a proof of Fx or ¬Fx. Using (9)(vi), we have a proof of a particular substitution, say ¬Fk. The question is whether there is an operation that transforms every proof of for all x, F(x) into a proof of 0 = 1. There is: given a proof of the universal quantification, apply it to generate a proof of Fk; this, together with the proof of ¬Fk, yields a proof of 0 = 1.

I am expecting for my attempts to make no sense at all as I did what I could to try to explain them intuitionistically. All help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

An interesting thing to point out is that the "rules" you have correspond to what we call [BHK Interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer%E2%80%93Heyting%E2%80%93Kolmogorov_interpretation).

## Exercice 1

The main problem is that you don't use the new meaning given to the negation ¬ (different from the classical logic).

- First, you should understand the implication A ⇒ B as a "transformer" from a proof of A to a proof of B.
  When you work with implications as A ⇒ B, first suppose A then prove B.
- The negation ¬A is A ⇒ 0. You should make use of that.

**Intuition** : Suppose that we have a proof of (X & Y) and take 0 as your new "goal". Use "function application" to solve the problem.

## Exercice 2

Hum...I don't understand why you wrote the first part of your attempt. It doesn't seem to be related to the question you suggest later. It seems to me that (c) is an *inference rule*. That is, given the top part you can infer the bottom part (forward reasoning).

There's also an alternative reading from bottom to top : if you want to prove the bottom part you have to prove the top part (backward reasoning).

For your last question, it seems that you're using the [principle of explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion). But in my opinion the right thing to do is to see (∀x.Fx) as a transformer : given an object x, it gives a proof of Fx (you can produce any Fx, including 0 = 1, with the inference rule (c) you have).

I may be wrong since I'm not sure to be right about my interpretation for your second exercise.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2165680/understanding-intuitionistic-logic) for the well-formatted question.